# Is it possible GitLab do only delivery (or deploy) the source codes manually to remote server?

Tags: deployment, gitlab

I started studying GitLab for my boss's order.

I found GitLab supports built-in CI/CD features.

But I don't want CI feature. Only to deliver code manually. 
...and the concept of CI/CD is too difficult to me.

Of course I am going to search this topic continuously, 
but also worried that it is impossible only to deliver code from GitLab Web repository to remote server.

Anyone who know this question? 
Please help me.

Comment: do you have experience with code versioning and more specific with git?

Comment: A little bit. It is not to try CI/CD right now, I just want to know is it possible. Because my team will use git from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab is one of the most flexible platforms to code versioning and CI/CD

almost everything is possible, but of course some things needs more expertise than other

In your case, delivering code manually will work without any problem.

But you need to understand more about git concepts
look at this article https://thepilcrow.net/explaining-basic-concepts-git-and-github/

forget the differences between github and gitlab now.... focus on understanding git (gitlab is just an inferface)

After that, when you start to study ci/cd you will discover the power of gitlab :D